# Shortcut to menu

Tags: winforms, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I create a shortcut to a menu in Windows Forms?

I think about something like in Visual Studio and Firefox, where I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and mainly menu item's shortcut letters have been **underlined**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ampersand (&) in front of the letter you want to use as a shortcut, like &File, in the text of the menu.

Also, if you're using Visual Studio, you should see the property for Shortcut Keys in the properties window as part of the designer.  This will give you more options (like Shift and/or Ctrl, etc.).